# Inno Setup close already open application without user interaction

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using Inno Setup to create installer for my product.
I want to close the already running application at the time of installer is running.

By using [`CloseApplications`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_closeapplicationsfilter) it shows below prompt to user

[image]

But I Don't want to give user second option *"Do not close the application"*.
Is this possible somehow?